# How to filter row in sql if column with comma seprated that contains with duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Sample` with data stored like below:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc, def, ghi |
| 2 | cbc, deb, bbb, cbc |
| 3 | aaa, bbb, ccc |
| 4 | ddd, ddd, eee |

I need output like:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc, def, ghi |
| 3 | aaa, bbb, ccc |

Comment: So what have SQL code you tried? Why do you think it's not working for you? Does it give an error?

Comment: Also, `bbb` appears in rows 2 and 3, so should your expected output only contain row 1?

Comment: You should seriously look into redesigning the table. Storing csv lists of values is a bad practice. It has poorer performance and often creates data integrity issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `EXISTS()`, `STRING_SPLIT()` and an appropriate `GROUP BY` clause is an option:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sample s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(s.Name, ',')
   GROUP BY RTRIM(LTRIM([value]))
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```